# Conditionally aggregate grouped data frame with different functions depending on values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following Pandas data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"val":[1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30, 40],
                   "group_id":["ones", "ones", "ones", "tens", "tens", "tens", "tens"],
                   "condition":["sum", "sum", "sum", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean"]})
```

I'd like to aggregate the data in `df["val"]` by grouping on `group_id` then applying a different aggregation function to each group. To determine which aggregation function to use, I'd like to set up a condition that references another column in `df`, namely `condition`.

Specifically, I'd like to take the sum of all elements in `val` for the `"ones"` group and the mean of all elements in the `"tens"` group. (But I don't need to pull the name of the aggregation function from `condition`. The `condition` column could be anything, as long as every group has the same condition, e.g. all `"ones"` correspond to `"sum"`. So maybe the `condition` column is redundant?)

I'd like to get the following result.

```
df_aggregated = pd.DataFrame({"group_id":["ones", "tens"],
                              "val_aggregated":["6", "25"]})
```

There's a clean way to do this with R and dplyr:

```
df <- tibble(val = c(1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30, 40),
             group_id = c("ones", "ones", "ones", "tens", "tens", "tens", "tens"),
             condition = c("sum", "sum", "sum", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean"))

df_aggregated <- df %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>% 
  summarise(val_aggregated = case_when(condition == "sum" ~ sum(val),
                                       condition == "mean" ~ mean(val),
                                       TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>% 
  distinct()
```

But I can't seem to find a good way to do this kind of aggregation in Pandas. Maybe the solution involves NumPy's `select()` function? Or would the Pandas-idiomatic way be to just loop over the grouped data structure?

Many thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: The fastest and easiest option is to aggregate both `df.groupby('group_id').val.agg(['mean', 'sum'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to groupby on both `group_id` and `condition` and aggregate:

```
(
    df.groupby(["group_id", "condition"])
    .agg(["sum", "mean"])
    .stack()
    .reset_index() 
     # keeps only rows where condition equals aggregates
    .query("condition==level_2")
    .drop(columns=["condition", "level_2"])
    .rename(columns={"val": "val_aggregated"})
)

    group_id    val_aggregated
0      ones         6
3      tens         25
```

Another way is to pivot the data, then aggregate:

```
result = df.pivot(columns=["group_id", "condition"], values="val")
result

group_id    ones    tens
condition   sum     mean
0           1.0     NaN
1           2.0     NaN
2           3.0     NaN
3           NaN     10.0
4           NaN     20.0
5           NaN     30.0
6           NaN     40.0
```

Get a pairing of `ones` and `teens` to `sum` and `mean`:

```
mapping = zip(*result.columns)
mapping = dict(zip(*mapping))
mapping
{'ones': 'sum', 'tens': 'mean'}
```

Drop the `condition` level on the columns and aggregate:

```
(
    result.droplevel(level="condition", axis="columns")
    .agg(mapping)
    .rename_axis(index="group_id")
    .reset_index(name="val_aggregated")
)


    group_id    val_aggregated
0       ones    6.0
1       tens    25.0
```

Another option, which is a bit similar to dplyr's solution is to use `np.where`, as you alluded to in your question :

```
group = df.groupby("group_id")

(
    df.assign(
        val_aggregate=np.where(
            df.condition.eq("sum"),
            group.val.transform("sum"),
            group.val.transform("mean"),
        )
    )
    .loc[:, ["group_id", "val_aggregate"]]
    .drop_duplicates()
)

    group_id    val_aggregate
0       ones        6
3       tens        25
```